# How can I install my extension with the status disabled?

Tags: xml, joomla, components, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

This is my XML file for the extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<extension method="upgrade" type="component" version="2.5">
<name>CS_KIALAPLUGIN</name>
<creationDate>March 17 2013</creationDate>
<author>Complusoft</author>
<authorUrl>http://www.complusoft.es</authorUrl>
<copyright></copyright>
<license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
<version>2.0.22c</version>
<description>VMKIALA_PLUGIN_DESC</description>

<scriptfile>install/kiala.php</scriptfile>

<administration>
        <files>
                <filename>kialaplugin.php</filename>
        </files>

</administration>

</extension>
```

Im looking for a parameter that installs this extension disabled instead of enabled.

Comment: In `install/kiala.php`, create a function that runs a database query to disable it in the `#__extensions` database table and call that function within the `postflight` function.

Comment: @Lodder could you please explain the postflight? Never heard of that :(

Comment: Basically you can run code within your install script at set times when installing or updating an extension: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Managing_Component_Updates_%28Script.php%29#postflight

Comment: @Lodder I was reading that just now but what im not sure is where do I get $type and $parent from? I made a function like that but its not working

Comment: I will be able to start you off with some code in a bit.

Comment: @Lodder cant wait! :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52120/discussion-between-monztaaa-and-lodder)

Answer (score 1):

Finally got round to testing the code I send you earlier and it's working fine:

**script.php**

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class com_kialapluginInstallerScript
{
    function install($parent) 
    {
        echo '<p>Install Successful</p>';
    }

    function postflight( $type, $parent )
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $fields = array(
            $db->quoteName('enabled') . ' = 0'
        );

        $conditions = array(
            $db->quoteName('element') . ' = ' . $db->quote('com_kialaplugin')
        );

        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__extensions'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

        $db->setQuery($query);

        $result = $db->query();
    }
}

?>
```

Hope this helps and will send you the zip when you're back on chat

Answer (score 0):

So such parameter exists in the xml file. So you have two main options

1. You must either disable it in the Extension Manager Component of Joomla.
2. You can perform a db request to unpublish the extension in the script file

Comment: I tried puting it in a script inside the XML file but it didnt work. It seems that the script either runs before or at the same time of the installation and it doesnt find the component yet in the DB.

Comment: I mean inside this script file ```<scriptfile>install/kiala.php</scriptfile>``` - But Lodder's got you on the right track :)